# How to override GetWebResponse

Tags: .net, web-services, soap, interop

I'm trying to do what this guy does here to parse the SOAP response manually:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webservices/Java_WS_NET.aspx

My problem is the proxy class that i have generated from the vendor's java web service wsdl does not have a method called GetWebResponse that i can override.

So when the author of the article does this:

```
WR = MyBase.GetWebResponse(the_webRequest)
```

**There is no equivalent GetWebResponse in my classes so what do i do?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is bringing back some memories from several years ago. Same exact problem, AXIS and .Net weren't playing together nicely. In my case it had something to do with AXIS wanting NULL properties to be set to an empty string and .Net assumed that NULL properties could just be ignored (or something similar, its been a while).

Anyway, you're probably adding a Service Reference instead of a Web Reference. Delete your current reference and add a new one but instead of entering anything on the "Add Service Reference" screen click the "Advanced" button and then click the "Add Web Reference" button. This will ultimately give you a class that you can override `GetWebResponse()` in.

I couldn't tell you what the difference between the two are except that in VS2008 the Web Reference was hidden in favor of Service Reference.

**EDIT**

Once you've got the Web Reference you need to derive a new class from it. For the example below I'm going to the following WSDL from Amazon:

`http://soap.amazon.com/schemas2/AmazonWebServices.wsdl`

Add a new class called `Test` (or probably come up with a better name). Have that class inherit the main class of the service. (The main class is probably the first class listed in `Reference.cs` but where ever it is it will inherit from `SoapHttpClientProtocol`). Then just override:

```
class Test : com.amazon.soap.AmazonSearchService
{
    protected override System.Net.WebResponse GetWebResponse(System.Net.WebRequest request)
    {
        return base.GetWebResponse(request);
    }
}
```

Comment: I added a "Web Reference" it created a Reference.cs file and all but i still don't see the GetWebResponse(). I don't know what i'm missing.

Comment: @capdragon, I added some instructions above. One you get this part make done make sure to re-read the article that you linked to on how to use this.

Comment: Thanks, i appreciate your patience and taking the time. +1 on all your comments/answers.